# How to setup Skrollr.js with AngularJS and RequireJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, skrollr, angular-directive

I'm having difficulties setting up Skrollr using AngularJS & RequirejS.

Some articles suggested to set up Skrollr as a directive and that is the approach that I have been following. Unfortunately, Skrollr is not able to initialize. Specifically, when I try to call the skrollr.init() from the directive I get an error saying that skrollr is not defined.

Below is my code:

#### directives.js

```
define(['directivesFactory', 'skrollr'], function(directivesFactory){

directivesFactory.directive('skrollr', [function(){  
    var directiveDefinitionObject = {
        link: function() {
            skrollr.init();
        }
    };

    return directiveDefinitionObject;
}]);
});
```

#### main.js

```
(function() {

'use strict';

require.config({
    baseUrl: 'js',
    paths: {
        'angular': 'libs/angular-1.3.9',
        'angularRoute': 'libs/angular-route-1.3.9',
        'bootstrap': 'libs/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min',
        'jquery': 'libs/jquery-1.11.0.min',
        'bootstrapJS': 'libs/bootstrap',
        'jqueryElastislide': 'libs/jquery.elastislide',
        'jqueryPpCustom' : 'libs/jquerypp.custom',
        'modernizrCustom' : 'libs/modernizr.custom.17475',
        'skrollr' : 'libs/skrollr.min'
    },
    shim: {
        'angular': {
            exports: 'angular'
        },
        'angularRoute': {
            deps: ['angular']
        },
        'jquery': {
            exports: '$'
        },
        'bootstrapJS': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'jqueryElastislide':{
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'jqueryPpCustom':{
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'skrollr': {
            exports: 'skrollr'
        }
    }
});

define('controllersFactory', ['angular'], function(angular) {
    return angular.module('app.controllers', []);
});

define('servicesFactory', ['angular'], function(angular) {
    return angular.module('app.services', []);
});

define('directivesFactory', ['angular'], function(angular) {
    return angular.module('app.directives', []);
}); 

define('app', [
    'angular',
    'angularRoute',
    'servicesFactory',
    'controllersFactory',
    'directivesFactory',
    ],
    function(angular) {
        return angular.module('app', ['app.services', 'app.controllers', 'app.directives', 'ngRoute']);
    }
);

require(['app', 
    'jquery',
    'skrollr',
    'bootstrap', 
    'bootstrapJS',
    'jqueryElastislide',
    'jqueryPpCustom',
    'modernizrCustom'], 
    function(app, 
        jquery, 
        skrollr,
        bootstrap, 
        bootstrapJS, 
        jqueryElastislide, 
        jqueryPpCustom, 
        modernizrCustom) {
    require([
            'controllers/mainController'
        ],
        function() {
            app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
                $routeProvider.
                    when('/', {templateUrl: 'templates/main.html', controller: "MainController"}).
                    otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
            }]);

            angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
        }
    );
});
})();
```

From web inspector, I see that skrollr.min.js is loaded before the directives.js file so I believe the directives should be able to call the functions within skrollr.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
define(['directivesFactory', 'skrollr'], function(directivesFactory){

directivesFactory.directive('skrollr', [function(){  
    var directiveDefinitionObject = {
        link: function() {
            skrollr.init();
        }
    };

    return directiveDefinitionObject;
}]);
});
```

You don't seem to have required skrollr here, you need to add the require.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

I've never tried adding the require in the directives ... would you mind elaborating on what you mean by that?

I thought adding require modules are to be done in the main.js file

Comment: In this particular file you actually do not fetch the code for skrollr from requirejs. You need to ask require for it. Even though you specified the path in your main file, it won't be available in this file unless you do that by calling require('skrollr', function(skrollr) { ... use skrollr ...} )

Comment: Thanks for your help.

I tinkered around some more and turns out the answer was really simple.
In my first line where i use the define() I included 'skrollr' as a dependency but I forgot to pass skrollr as a parameter alongside directivesFactory.

All that I had to do was change the first line to:

define(['directivesFactory', 'skrollr'], function(directivesFactory, skrollr){